# Link SQL Server data to MS Access database with filters

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc, ms-access-2016

I would like to create a link from an SQL Server database to an MS Access database for reporting purposes. I don't need all the data from the table just the past few years worth. Is there a way through Access VBA or MS Access tools to only bring in the rows I need rather then all rows?

Comment: Yes. You can do this by creating in Access VBA a QueryDef that is a PASS THROUGH QUERY. It passes the parameter to SQL Server and only returns the rows required.
Another way is to create a table on SQL Server that holds filter condition values corresponding to columns in a table. You create a view that is filtered by this parameter table. Update the values in the parameter table from Access to change the results of the view.

Comment: Creating a view on SQL Server that returns only the information you want is also another way of doing this. It would also allow you to completely ignore any data columns you don't need for this reporting.

Comment: I'll check out QueryDef and see if that offers the solution I need. Thanks.

Comment: @LaughingVergil mostly in MS Access you need to add an index through VBA when you create a view, but I do like views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to our DBA. I'm going to create a view. cloudsafe thanks for the suggestion, I just didn't have the time to investigate QueryDef in Access, but I've I made a note of it for possibly future usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how a parameter table works in SQL Server, that can easily be updated from Access. The table is updated or inserted with the current username and the filter value, changing the rows returned by the view.

`create table Params (
        usrname as nvarchar(100) CONSTRAINT [df_load_date] DEFAULT @@SUSER_NAME
      , pvalue as nvarchar(100))
    Insert into params (pvalue) values ( 'MytableName')
    Create view vw_test
    as
    select * from sysobjects where name in (
        Select pvalue from Params where usrname = @@SUSER_NAME)`

Answer (score -1):

Connect to the SQL Server database in Access using the External Data tab via ODBC and use SQL in ACCESS or the query desinger on the Create Tab to query the data you need.
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE DATEFIELD > whatever date

Comment: This will return all the rows from the table, then filter them with the WHERE clause. It can cause network problems and slowness.

Comment: Are you saying import all the data and query it independently to get the rows I need? If so I don't want to use this method. I only want to bring in the rows I need and then I will query those rows.

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL SERVER database?  If so, create a view in the SQL Server DB and connect to the view through access or have a DBA create the view for you.

Comment: I don't have enough privilege to create a view.

Comment: Using a where clause in SQL does NOT pull or grab all rows and then filter  - so couldsafe is 100% wrong on this issue.  this includes using + building a query in the access client that based on linked tables.

Comment: Pretty sure I was the one that recommended having a DBA to create a view for you